# console.log is not working inside vue.js script

Tags: vue.js, console.log

I am quite new to vue.js, and I am trying to build an basic application that displays data fetched from an API.

I do not understand why I cannot use console.log inside my scripts :

```
<script>

    import Header from './components/layout/Header.vue'
    import Todos from './components/Todo.vue'

    export default {
      name: 'app',
      components: {
        Todos,
        Header,
      },
      data () {
        return {
          todos : []
        }
      },
      methods : {

        created () {
            fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos')
            .then( resp => resp.json())
            .then( data => {

                console.log(data);
            })
            .catch(err => err)

        }
      }
    }
</script>
```

I always got "unexpected console statement"

Does anybody knows how I can console log stuff inside vue scripts ? Am I missing something ??

Thanks a lot !!

Comment: Can you please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), e.g. in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/boilerplate/vue)?

Comment: There is a syntax error in your code. You embedded created inside your methods

Answer (score 4):

You can try

```
methods: {
 log(msg){
  console.log(msg); 
 }
}
```

And when you want to write things to console, use:

```
{{ log(message) }}
```

Comment: Thank you for you're answer ! I have tried that : however, it crashes the same error : I cannot write any console.log in my scripts : it always returns the same error "unexpected console statement" 

I have the feeling that it is not the right to log stuff in the console with vue but I don't understand why ...

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to call `return` when you turn it to `json()` like this

```
.then(resp => return resp.json())
```

Also not sure if you have a typo but your `created()` method should not be inside of the `methods` object.

should look like this

```
<script>
  export default{
  name: '',
  data(){
    return {

    }
  },
  methods:{

  },
  created() {

  }
}
</script>
```

And maybe try `console.log()` in the `error` section of your fetch method as well in case there is an error receiving the data.

```
.catch(err => {
   console.log(err.response.data)
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! However it is the console.log statement that is causing the issue : it isn't working it any of my scripts : if I console.log in a vue component it crashes an error ...

Comment: That's strange, I don't believe it is an issue with vue. I use it all the time.

Comment: hi @Jonas did you find the solution. I'm facing the same. `console` is not working inside Vue script

Answer (score -1):

How about using async/await to help break up the flow?

```
export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {
    Todos,
    Header,
  },
  data () {
    return {
      todos : []
    }
  },
  methods : {
    async created () {
      try {
        const resp = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos');
        const data = resp.json();
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
        console.log(data);
      } catch (err => console.error(err))
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you're answer ! It seems to be the same issue than for the other issues : I cannot write any console.log in my scripts : it always returns the same error "unexpected console statement" I have the feeling that it is not the right to log stuff in the console with vue but I don't understand why ...

Comment: Are you using a linter? Maybe you have this rule set and that's the error you are seeing: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-console
Try adding `// eslint-disable-next-line no-console` on the line before your console statement to see if that fixes it. If so, it's a linting rule, not a vue / javascript error.

Comment: You are right !! It seems to fix the issue I had, however I now have a TypeError: Cannot read property 'log' of undefined.
Do you know what causes this issue ?

Comment: Odd... not sure what could cause that one, but try some other console functions like `console.warn` / `console.error` and try using `console.log` in other places (with that comment to disable the linter) and see if any of that works. Try to narrow down where / what the issue is.